# Google Rich Snippet for a childcare local business

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

Can you please help me to figure it out how to set Google Rich Snippet for a childcare service?

My specific question is, should I register `itemtype` as `LocalBusiness` like

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
```

or directly as `ChildCare` like

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ChildCare">
```

Comment: I think your second question is not really based on or related to your first question. Would you agree to remove the 2nd question and create a separate question post for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, you should always choose the most-specific type.

So if your business matches the description for [`ChildCare`](http://schema.org/ChildCare) ("A Childcare center."), you should use this type instead of the more general [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness) (or even the most general [`Thing`](http://schema.org/Thing)).

Every complying consumer should be able to understand that `ChildCare` is some kind of `LocalBusiness`. Only if the type is very new (or if they no longer update/maintain their product), consumers may need some time until they recognize it.

If you want to make sure that those consumers also understand it, you could provide both types:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ChildCare http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
</div>
```

But that’s typically not needed.

Comment: Thanks unor it was helpful,